# magento custom payment method form not showing on live site but working on staging

Tags: php, magento

I have custom payment module.
I found that in onestepheckout this is the way the payment method form is rendered:

```
<?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
<dd id="container_payment_method_<?php echo $_code; ?>" class="payment-method" <?php      if(!$this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code || !($hide_nonfree_methods && $_code == 'free')): ?> style="display:none"<?php endif; ?>>

<?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
```

So, for my method $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method) is FALSE. ¿why?
Please help me,

Comment: those are custom extensions so contact the respective module provider support to solve your issues

Answer (score 0):

check your back-end,

```
system > configuration > sales > payment methods
```

any method enabled?

if nothing *enabled*, it will returns **FALSE**.

Comment: these are enabled including my custom payment method.

Comment: try to var_dump(get_class($this)); on that file. and see what you got?